# Pandas: How can I flatten only the lists of list for a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataset that has a particular column having values similar to the dummy data frame below with column col2. The column entries are either a list or a list of lists and I want to flatten only the list of lists to a single list.

```
    col1                  col2
0    tom                  [10]
1   nick              [15, 24]
2   juli  [[16, 14], [19, 17]]
3  harry              [23, 15]
4  frank  [[15, 16], [50, 30]]
```

I want my expected dataframe to resemble something like this -

```
col1              col2
0    tom              [10]
1   nick          [15, 24]
2   juli  [16, 14, 19, 17]
3  harry          [23, 15]
4  frank   [15, 16, 50, 3]
```

I tried using `DF['col2'] = DF.col2.apply(lambda x: sum(x, []))` but it didn't work returning the error -  `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`

How can I solve this elegantly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), as follows:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].map(np.ravel)
```

Note that this assumed your list are real list instead of string looking like list.  If not the case, you can convert the string to real list first, as follows:

```
import ast
df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

# Then, run the code:
df['col2'] = df['col2'].map(np.ravel)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

    col1              col2
0    tom              [10]
1   nick          [15, 24]
2   juli  [16, 14, 19, 17]
3  harry          [23, 15]
4  frank  [15, 16, 50, 30]
```

Comment: Panda has `.ravel()` baked in, you can do `df['col2'] = df['col2'].ravel`

Comment: @Antoine  Note that `Series.ravel()` returns **a single ndarray** containing the data of the given series object.   It does NOT give separate flattened list for each element as required in this question.  The result when assigned back to the same column only returns the same unflattened elements without change.

Comment: @Antoine  Welcome!  I agree that this Pandas function is really doing something that is out of our expectation  :-D   That's why we sometimes still need to resort to use numpy functions.  :-)